# tns preview doesn't work due to 404 error

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I started to learn Nativescript just today. I go to play.nativescript.org and start the tutorial, then I want to work locally so I do exactly like the instruction but it gives me an error when I try to run `tns preview`:
[image]

[image]

How to make it work?

Comment: Can you share the link of this playground? It seems that one of the dependencies in the project is no longer available.

Comment: Just go to https://play.nativescript.org, hit the download button  and do what they tell you(the first screenshot above) and you'll see